# Conversion of XML to Json

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Hi I have xml like this -

This is node of that xml-

```
<item col_sort='20160102' Month='Jan-2016' Week='Week 1' Date='01/02/2016' Name='A' Id='1'
                    Column1='0' Column1Agg1='1410.00' Column1Agg2='405.00' Column1Agg3='0'
                    Column2='38' Column2Agg1='2976' Column2Agg2='79' Column2Agg3='79'
                    Column3='0.32' Column3Agg1='0.56'  Column3Agg2='0.41' Column3Agg3='0.41' 
                    Column4='11.42' Column4Agg1='8.48'  Column4Agg2='9.55'  Column4Agg3='9.55'
                    Column5='8.76' Column5Agg1='2.97' Column5Agg2='9.81' Column5Agg3='9.81'
                    Column6='-1'  Column6Agg1='-2'  Column6Agg2='-1'  Column6Agg3='-1'
                    Column7='-99' Column7Agg1='99.9' Column7Agg2='-99' Column7Agg3='-99'
                    Column8='-99.00' Column8Agg1='8.00' Column8Agg2='-99.00' Column8Agg3='-99.00'
                    Column9='17.82' Column9Agg1='9.96' Column9Agg2='17.84' Column9Agg3='17.84' 
                    Column10='18.18' Column10Agg1='10.51' Column10Agg2='18.28' Column10Agg3='18.28'
                    Column11='-2' Column11Agg1='-2'  Column11Agg2='-2' Column11Agg3='-2'
                    Column12='7.9' Column12Agg1='44.6' Column12Agg2='7.6'  Column12Agg3='7.6'  
                    Column13='12.86' Column13Agg1='10.48' Column13Agg2='12.68' Column13Agg3='12.68' />
```

Now, here the Agg is prefixed to the child node. So, here in one node we have all the children value with the parent. Here Agg1 represents a parent.
Agg2 is the child of Agg1 and Agg3 is the child of Agg2. And the nodes which don't have prefix are the leaf node.

```
json = [ {
         "Month": "Dec-2016",
         "Column1Agg1": "1410.00",
         "Column2Agg1": "2976",
         "Column3Agg1": "0.56",
         "Column4Agg1": "8.48",,
         "Column5Agg1": "2.97",
         "Column6Agg1": "-2",
         "Column7Agg1": "-99.9",
         "Column8Agg1": "8.00",
         "Column9Agg1": "9.96",
         "Column10Agg1": "10.51",
         "Column11Agg1": "-2",
         "Column12Agg1": "44.6",
         "Column13Agg1": "10.48",
         "children" : [
         {"Week": "Week 1",
         "Column1Agg2": "405.00",
         "Column2Agg2": "79",
         "Column3Agg2": "0.41",
         "Column4Agg2": "9.55",
         "Column5Agg2": "9.81",
         "Column6Agg2": "-1",
         "Column7Agg2": "-99",
         "Column8Agg2": "-99.00",
         "Column9Agg2": "17.84",
         "Column10Agg2": "18.28",
         "Column11Agg2": "-2",
         "Column12Agg2": "7.6",
         "Column13Agg2": "12.68",
         "children" : [{
          "Date": "01/02/2016",
         "Column1Agg3": "405.00",
         "Column2Agg3": "79",
         "Column3Agg3": "0.41",
         "Column4Agg3": "9.55",
         "Column5Agg3": "9.81",
         "Column6Agg3": "-1",
         "Column7Agg3": "-99",
         "Column8Agg3": "-99.00",
         "Column9Agg3": "17.84",
         "Column10Agg3": "18.28",
         "Column11Agg3": "-2",
         "Column12Agg3": "7.6",
         "Column13Agg3": "12.68",
         "children" : [{
        "Name" : "A",
        "Id" : "1",
         "Column1": "0",
         "Column2": "38",
         "Column3": "0.32",
         "Column4": "11.42",
         "Column5": "8.76",
         "Column6": "-1",
         "Column7": "-99",
         "Column8": "-99.00",
         "Column9": "17.82",
         "Column10": "18.18",
         "Column11": "-2",
         "Column12": "7.9",
         "Column13": "12.86"

            }]
          }]
          }]
          }]
```

How to convert this type of xml to json with children.

Any ideas how to do this

Comment: Please also add a question. You've described something, what is the problem you are having?

Comment: open google and type "javascript xml to json" and click the first link.

Comment: @TahaPaksu  it will not create child nodes it will just convert...I want to create child nodes

Comment: how do you define children?

Comment: The children or leaf node will not have prefix...parent node will have prefix Agg1 and their children has prefix Agg2 and so on

Comment: where does week 5 come from?

Comment: @TahaPaksu sorry corrected it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141401/discussion-between-taha-paksu-and-shv22).

Answer (score 0):

I coded this with regex. You might add some extra checks if you need.

```js
var data = "<item col_sort='20160102' Month='Jan-2016' Week='Week 1' Date='01/02/2016' Name='A' Id='1' \
                    Column1='0' Column1Agg1='1410.00' Column1Agg2='405.00' Column1Agg3='0' \
                    Column2='38' Column2Agg1='2976' Column2Agg2='79' Column2Agg3='79' \
                    Column3='0.32' Column3Agg1='0.56'  Column3Agg2='0.41' Column3Agg3='0.41'  \
                    Column4='11.42' Column4Agg1='8.48'  Column4Agg2='9.55'  Column4Agg3='9.55'\
                    Column5='8.76' Column5Agg1='2.97' Column5Agg2='9.81' Column5Agg3='9.81'\
                    Column6='-1'  Column6Agg1='-2'  Column6Agg2='-1'  Column6Agg3='-1'\
                    Column7='-99' Column7Agg1='99.9' Column7Agg2='-99' Column7Agg3='-99'\
                    Column8='-99.00' Column8Agg1='8.00' Column8Agg2='-99.00' Column8Agg3='-99.00'\
                    Column9='17.82' Column9Agg1='9.96' Column9Agg2='17.84' Column9Agg3='17.84' \
                    Column10='18.18' Column10Agg1='10.51' Column10Agg2='18.28' Column10Agg3='18.28'\
                    Column11='-2' Column11Agg1='-2'  Column11Agg2='-2' Column11Agg3='-2'\
                    Column12='7.9' Column12Agg1='44.6' Column12Agg2='7.6'  Column12Agg3='7.6'  \
                    Column13='12.86' Column13Agg1='10.48' Column13Agg2='12.68' Column13Agg3='12.68' />";

    var getChildren = function(i, search){
  var result = {};
     var re = new RegExp("Column([0-9]+)Agg"+i+"='([0-9.-]+)'", "g"), m, p = 0;       
  do {
      m = re.exec(search);            
      if (m) {       
          result["Column" + m[1] + "Agg" + i] = m[2];
          p++;
      }
  } while (m);   
    if(p>0){
   result.children = getChildren(i+1, search);
  }
  return result;
 }

  var m;
 var results = {};
 
 results = getChildren(1, data); 
 results.Month = /Month='([^']+)'/g.exec(data)[1];
 results.children.Week = /Week='([^']+)'/g.exec(data)[1];
 results.children.children.Date = /Date='([^']+)'/g.exec(data)[1];
 
 console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for that...but slight misunderstanding Column1Agg1 is the parent and Column1 is leaf node but in here result is I think opposite

Comment: Can you fix your example with what you say? I'll modify my answer then.

Comment: why you have added '/' before each line...now how could to do it in my reponse?

Comment: This operator is used to concatenate the lines together, it's just my test data. You need to define 'data' as your own input.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would start by converting your insane XML input into something more sanitary, along the lines of:

```
<item col_sort='20160102' Month='Jan-2016' Week='Week 1' Date='01/02/2016' Name='A' Id='1'>
  <column nr='1' value='0'>
    <agg nr='1'>1410.00</agg>
    <agg nr='2'>405.00</agg>
    <agg nr='3'>0</agg>
  </column>
  <column nr='2' value='38'>
    <agg nr='1'>2976</agg>
    <agg nr='2'>79</agg>
    <agg nr='3'>79</agg>
  </column>
etc
```

That's easily enough done with XSLT. Here's a sketch:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="@*" group-by="f:colNr(name())">
  <xsl:sort select="number(current-grouping-key())"/>
  <column nr="{current-grouping-key()}">
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
      <xsl:sort select="f:aggNr(name())">
        <agg nr="{f:aggNr(name())}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
```